# Efficient way of ensuring newness of a set

Tags: c++, c, algorithm, set

Given set `N = {1,...,n}`, consider `P` different pre-existing subsets of `N`. A subset, `S_p`, is characterized by the 0-1 `n` vector `x_p` where the `i`th element is 0 or 1 depending on whether the `i`th (of `n`) items is part of the subset or not. Let us call such `x_p`s *indicator vectors*.

For e.g., if `N={1,2,3,4,5}`, subset `{1,2,5}` is represented by vector `(1,0,0,1,1)`.

Now, given `P` pre-existing subsets and their associated vectors `x_p`s.

A candidate subset denoted by vector `y`is computed.

What is the most efficient way of checking whether `y` is already part of the set of `P` pre-existing subsets or whether `y` is indeed a new subset not part of the `P` subsets?

The following are the methods I can think of:

(Method 1) Basically, we have to do an element by element check against all pre-existing sets. Pseudocode follows:

```
for(int p = 0; p < P; p++){
     //(check if x_p == y by doing an element by element comparison)
     int i;
     for(i = 0; i < n; i++){
         if(x_pi != y_i){
             i = 999999;
         }             
     }
     if(i < 999999)
          return that y is pre-existing

}
return that y is new
```

(Method 2) Another thought that comes to mind is to store the decimal equivalent of the indicator vectors `x_p`s (where the indicator vectors are taken to be binary representations) and compare it with the decimal equivalent of `y`. That is, if set of `P` pre-existing sets is: `{ (0,1,0,0,1), (1,0,1,1,0) }`, the stored decimals for this set would be `{9, 22}`. If `y` is `(0,1,1,0,0)`, we compute `12` and check this against the set `{9, 22}`. The benefit of this method is that for each new `y`, we don't have to check against the `n` elements of every pre-existing set. We can just compare the decimal numbers.

Question 1. It appears to me that (Method 2) should be more efficient than (Method 1). For (Method 2), is there an efficient way (inbuilt library function in C/C++) that converts the `x_p`s and `y` from binary to decimal? What should be data type of these indicator variables? For e.g., `bool y[5];` or `char y[5];`?

Question 2. Is there any method more efficient than (Method 2)?

Comment: What's the maximum value of `n`?

Comment: See if a [Bloom filter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bloom_filter) helps.

Comment: @user3386109 Upto 1000

Comment: If `n` is 1000, then the decimal equivalents are 1000 bit numbers. So an array of sixteen 64-bit numbers, or thirty-two 32-bit numbers.

Comment: Yes, even (Method 2) can be problematic. Is there any other efficient way?

Comment: How many pre-existing subsets would you expect to have?

Comment: @user3386109 P can vary also upto 1000 or so.

Comment: Oh, that's not too bad. In C++, you could convert the `x_p` vectors into `string`s and store the strings in a `std::set`.

Comment: @user3386109 That sounds promising. Could I bother you to provide an answer with details of how it is better than Method 1 or Method 2 that I can accept?

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Is there any implementation library of that filter?

Comment: Please read the description of tags before applying them. In particular, you will find explanation why it's a bad idea to combine C and C++ tags and when there are exceptions. Pick one language!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you've noticed, there's a trivial isomorphism between your indicator vectors and N-bit integers. That means the answer to your question 2 is "no": the tools available for maintain a set and testing membership in it are the same as integers (hash tables bring the normal approach). A commented mentioned Bloom fillers, which can efficiently test membership at the risk of some false positives, but Bloom filters are generally for much larger data sizes than you're looking at.

As for your question 1: Method 2 is reasonable, and it's even easier than you think. While `vector<bool>` doesn't give you an easy way to turn it into integer blocks,  on implementations I'm aware of it's already implemented this way (the C++ standard allows special treatment of that particular vector type, something that is generally considered nowadays to have been a poor decision, but which occasionally yields some benefit). And those vectors are hashable. So just keep an `unordered_set<vector<bool>>` around, and you'll get performance which is reasonably close to the optimum. (If you know `N` at compile time you may want to prefer `bitset` to `vector<bool>`.)

Comment: So, if I understand right, I can have `std::vector<std::vector<bool> > preexistingsets;` and `std::vector<bool> candidateset;` Then, to check if `candidateset` is preexisting, I should just do a for loop, looping through each of the preexisting set and checking element by element? Or, is there a library function I can use ? I do know N at compile time. So, I will also look at `bitset`.

Comment: I think I understand `unordered_set`. So, I can have `unordered_set<bitset <N>> preexistingsets;`. Let me experiment.

Comment: @Tryer You can just compare two `vector<bool>`s directly with `==`. The operator will take care of looping over vectors' contents, hopefully optimized to compare byte-size chunks or larger, rather than bit by bit. Same for `bitset`. You don't need to write your own per-element comparison.

Comment: @Sneftel I have the following: `std::unordered_set<std::bitset<1000>> S;` Suppose I want to add indicator vector `10011000...0` into `S`. Should I do a `std::bitset<1000> bset;` first then followed by appropriate `bset.set(index);` then finally followed by `S.insert(bset);` ? Is that the most efficient ? Or is there something equivalent of `emplace_back` or some such that helps build the `bitset` directly into the `unordered_set` instead of first creating it outside and then copying it into the container?

Comment: Just build the bitset and then insert it. That's not going to be your performance bottleneck.

Answer (score -1):

Method 2 can be optimized by calculating the decimal equivalent of the given subset and hashing it using modulus 1e9+7. This results in different decimal numbers every time since N<=1000(No collision occurs).

```
#define M 1000000007  //big prime number
unordered_set<long long> subset;  //containing decimal representation of all the 
                                  //previous found subsets

/*fast computation of power of 2*/
long long Pow(long long num,long long pow){
    long long result=1;
    while(pow)
    {
        if(pow&1)
        {
            result*=num;
            result%=M;
        }
        num*=num;
        num%=M;
        pow>>=1;
    }
    return result;
}
/*checks if subset pre exists*/
bool check(vector<bool> booleanVector){
    long long result=0;
    for(int i=0;i<booleanVector.size();i++)
        if(booleanVector[i])
            result+=Pow(2,i);
    return (subset.find(result)==subset.end());
}
```

Comment: `2^1000 > 1e9+7` (by quite a large margin). By the pigeonhole principle, you can't use a modulus (or other means of hashing) to reduce the range without causing collisions.

Comment: Finally, your method of using `Pow` in a loop to calculate the integer corresponding to the indicator vector is inefficient: it would be better to build the entire result up a bit at a time by shifting and adding rather than using exponentiation by squaring (`O(n)` versus `O(n log n)`).

Comment: I have tried and tested the code using M = 1e9+7 and no collision occurs until 5e6 as done in the code. [code](https://pastebin.com/CdSVQcAn). Also your 2nd comment removes a factor of log(N) only which does not matter much as N<=1000.

Comment: Collisions are *unlikely*. But you cannot claim that they are impossible based only on a few tests. If you work at it a bit, you will find a pair of bit vectors which have the same hash.

Comment: Indeed, based on your comment, you did find one. So, given that a collision exists, what stops the very first two bitvectors from being that pair?

Comment: Collisions are actually made less common by you failing to apply the modulus after the addition. Nevertheless, by comparing the number of possible vectors to the number of possible hashes, you can easily see that collisions become inevitable as the size of the set grows.

Comment: I agree but the problem requires for N<=1000 so the solution works.

Comment: No, it doesn't. With N=1000 and P=2 your solution may fail. Read rici's comment again.